# How get a name of child-class in a body of parent-class

Tags: c#, reflection

[C#]

I have classes:

```
public class ChildClass: ParentClass {
   // ... 
}

public class ParentClass {

   public GetClassName() {
       // ...
   }

}
```

And code:

```
var obj = new ChildClass();
string className = obj.GetClassName(); // <---- Here I want to get "ChildClass"
```

I know it may be done using Reflection. But I dont know how. Help me please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string className = obj.GetType().FullName;
```

If you are doing this in a method on the parent class, just do:

```
string className = GetType().FullName;
```